# Mesh of vertices shown in viewport but not in render: how to render?

Tags: rendering, vertices, point-clouds

I have a mesh which only consists of vertices. The mesh is essentially a point cloud. I can see the object in the viewport but I can't render it. I want to create a quick animation video where the camera moves around the object. How can I achieve it in the fastest/easiest way? Is there a way to render the viewport view?

Comment: I just watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuVZGDbly3g does that help?

Comment: Hello :). Sure thing. You can render your viewport view through *View > Viewport Render Animation.*

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea. Are the vertices joined together? What I mean is, are they considered one whole object? If so, you may be able to go to the properties panel, and scroll around in object context tab. There's an area there called "visibility". It has a checkbox that lets it be shown in renders. Perhaps it is unchecked by default? I hope this helps.